# how to send variable to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I am sending a tuple as my variable to javascript. But i could not find a way. I am using bottle framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Encode it into JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). It'll convert to a javascript array.

Answer (score 2):

A related tip to add to @Oil's point, Bottle returns JSON by default of you return a dict:

```
@route('/resource.json')
def resource_json():
    response = dict(
        data=('tuple', 'of', 'things'))
return response
```

See http://bottle.paws.de/page/docs#output-casting